# Parsing variables with dot notation in Extjs

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

The values are getting null in grid in Extjs when i am parsing these values from json,basically this is because the properties label are with dots.

```
"properties": {
            "financialYear": "2009",
            "employee.employeeId": "12345",
            "employee.employeeName": "abc"
        }
```

How do i get employee.employeeId value in .js to be displayed in Extjs grid.

Right now i am mapping like this in .js,

```
Ext.define('DocProperties',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'financialYear', type: 'string'},
    {name:'employeeId', mapping:'properties.employee.employeeId',type: 'string'},
]});
```

and for display in grid panel i am accessing like this,

```
{
        width:100,
        header: "Employee ID",
        dataIndex: 'employeeId',
        sortable: true
    }
```

any solution or workaround for this.

---

@DmitryB thanks,But this did not solve my problem,I have my store like this

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'DocResult',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'sample-data.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            useSimpleAccessors: true
        }
    }
});
```

and in my model i defined like this

```
Ext.define('DocResult',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
    {name:'employeeId', mapping:'properties.employee.employeeId',type: 'string'}

] });
```

and then also in my Ext grid display the empty value comes .Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking through the source code, you might try the following:

```
mapping:'properties["employee.employeeId"]'
```

Try this in combination with `useSimpleAccessors` set to either `true` or `false`, and let me know what the outcome is.

Comment: Hi BigSean...Thanks a lot..it worked by setting useSimpleAccessors to false and mapping as you said..Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the useSimpleAccessors option to true. Its false by default.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-useSimpleAccessors

EDIT: also based on the Store definition you provided in a different answer the JSON reader config needs to change to `root: "properties"`

Unless you did not provide the full JSON sample and properties is wrapped in a "results" object then you need set root: "results", and records: "properties"

Comment: Thanks DmitryB..i will do it in comments..Yes i used simpleAccessors property and mapping suggested by BigSean..it worked.